# Called From Wrong Thread Exception with AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, asyncsocket, thread-exceptions

I keep getting a CalledFromWrongThreadException even if i throw it into AsyncTask's DoInBackground method! Can anyone tell me why and how to fix it?

```
/**
     * Recognizes key words in responseTexts and runs the appropriate function
     * @param responseText
     */
    private void responseHandler(String responseText) {
        if(responseText.startsWith("Notes", 0)) {
            notes.add(responseText);
            new DownloadFilesTask().execute("WriteInternal" , null, null);
        }
    }
```

this is my AsyncTask class

```
private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    protected String doInBackground(String... command) {
    if(command[0].equals("WriteInternal") {
        //write to internal storage
    FileOutputStream fOut = null;
    OutputStreamWriter osw = null;
    try{
        fOut = openFileOutput("notes.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
        for (int i = 0; i < notes.size(); i++){
            osw.write(notes.get(i) + "\n");
        }
        osw.close();
        fOut.close();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace(System.err);
    }

    notesListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);  //refreshes the listView

       }
else {
        sendCommand(command[0]);
        return null;
}
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... progress) {}
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {}
}
```

Here's the stacktrace I got:

```
05-22 15:14:20.370: E/AndroidRuntime(11730): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
05-22 15:14:20.370: E/AndroidRuntime(11730): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
05-22 15:14:20.370: E/AndroidRuntime(11730):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)
05-22 15:14:20.370: E/AndroidRuntime(11730):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
05-22 15:14:20.370: E/AndroidRuntime(11730):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
05-22 15:14:20.370: E/AndroidRuntime(11730):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
05-22 15:14:20.370: E/AndroidRuntime(11730):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
05-22 15:14:20.370: E/AndroidRuntime(11730):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
05-22 15:14:20.370: E/AndroidRuntime(11730):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
05-22 15:14:20.370: E/AndroidRuntime(11730):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
05-22 15:14:20.370: E/AndroidRuntime(11730):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
05-22 15:14:20.370: E/AndroidRuntime(11730): Caused by: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
05-22 15:14:20.370: E/AndroidRuntime(11730):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:4039)
05-22 15:14:20.370: E/AndroidRuntime(11730):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.invalidateChild(ViewRootImpl.java:722)
05-22 15:14:20.370: E/AndroidRuntime(11730):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.invalidateChildInParent(ViewRootImpl.java:771)
05-22 15:14:20.370: E/AndroidRuntime(11730):    at android.view.ViewGroup.invalidateChild(ViewGroup.java:4005)
05-22 15:14:20.370: E/AndroidRuntime(11730):    at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:8576)
05-22 15:14:20.370: E/AndroidRuntime(11730):    at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:8527)
05-22 15:14:20.370: E/AndroidRuntime(11730):    at android.widget.AbsListView.resetList(AbsListView.java:1734)
05-22 15:14:20.370: E/AndroidRuntime(11730):    at android.widget.ListView.resetList(ListView.java:502)
05-22 15:14:20.370: E/AndroidRuntime(11730):    at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:442)
05-22 15:14:20.370: E/AndroidRuntime(11730):    at com.nelson.jarvisclientics.Notes$DownloadFilesTask.doInBackground(Notes.java:281)
05-22 15:14:20.370: E/AndroidRuntime(11730):    at com.nelson.jarvisclientics.Notes$DownloadFilesTask.doInBackground(Notes.java:1)
05-22 15:14:20.370: E/AndroidRuntime(11730):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
05-22 15:14:20.370: E/AndroidRuntime(11730):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
05-22 15:14:20.370: E/AndroidRuntime(11730):    ... 5 more
```

Comment: It would also be helpful to post the stack trace you receive from running this code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try wrapping your file access code with `runOnUIThread(new Runnable{/*code goes here*/}())`

Comment: Just a note:  It might be better and more with Android's design principles to do as others have said and handle this in onPostExecute().  Just cache your file, then actually write it in onPostExecute().

Comment: You should not do file access on the ui thread.   notesListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter) has to be done on the ui Thread. But with AsyncTask you do that in onPostExecute() which is executing on the ui thread.

Comment: This fixed the problem I was having but I still don't get why. I was adding elements to my list in onProgressUpdate (which runs on UI thread) and got this exception, when I added this it stopped.

Answer (score 2):

The reason you are getting this exception is because your are trying to update the UI in the doInBackground() method of your AsyncTask.  This is happening when you set the adapter for your listview here: `notesListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);  //refreshes the listView`

You should move this to onPostExecute.  Update the UI in onPostExecute and display any error messages if necessary.

Also note that you are calling handleCommand() in the background as well; make sure that this isn't going to update the UI as well!

Answer (score 1):

You can use onPostExecute which runs on the UI thread... It's the basic of using asynctask.

Comment: I added a comment to my solution above suggesting this is the better method.